# Android: register one receiver many times

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, download-manager

I am downloading an Android app from the server using the `DownloadManaegr` class. A broadcast receiver is registered when the download is completed. When the `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` intent is received, a bar notification is displayed. To install the app, the notification should be cliccked. This is what I am doing:

```
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) DownloadApplicationActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(MY_LINK));
    req.setTitle(MY_TITLE)
                    .setDescription("Downloading ....")
                    // download the package to the /sdcard/downlaod path.
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                            MY_PATH);
            long enqueue = dm.enqueue(req);
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(0DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));        

    BroadcastReceiver receiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
int id = 0;
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setFilterById(enqueue);
            Cursor c =dm.query(query);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    // show a notification bar.
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"",System.currentTimeMillis());

                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    // when the notification is clicked, install the app.
                            i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory() + APP_PATH)),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                    activity, 0, i, 0);
                            notification.setLatestEventInfo(activity, MY_TEXT, MY_TEXT,pendingIntent);
                            notification.number += 1;
                            notificationManager.notify(id++, notification);
                   }
            }           
    };
```

When two apps are downloaded at the same time, only one notification is displayed -the second notification-. I am missing the first one. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are calling notify with same id i.e '0' in your case, and the docs says it should be unique every time.

I think you should give different number everytime in place of 0.

```
notificationManager.notify( 0, notification);
```

below is what document says..

```
public void notify (int id, Notification notification)
```

Posts a notification to be shown in the status bar. **If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.**

Comment: I am doing that, notificationManager.notify( id, notification);
I will edit my code. the problem is that I am missing the first notification when two apps are downloaded at the same i.e before any notification is received.

Comment: The problem is: the first receiver is unregistered when the second one is registered.

Comment: so what stopping you to register first reciever too, and what makes you use two receiver!!

Comment: I am registering the first receiver, but when the second is registered, the first is unregistered .

Comment: You don't need to register same Receiver twice

Comment: I want to detect when the first download is completed. I register a Receiver for that. If I want to detect the second download, I don't need to register a second Receiver?

Comment: Y don't you have one receiver and listen for every download and show notification